# garbage collection in python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, weak-references

When implementing a thread that is intended to periodically read from a stream, I cannot manage to make the thread stop correctly. This is only the case when the callback function that I use is implemented as a method of the agent (`Worker`). See this example (python v3.10.11):

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
import weakref


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    """This class periodically reads from a stream."""

    def __init__(self, stream_key, callback):
        super().__init__()

        self._stream_key: str = stream_key
        self._handlers = {callback}

        self._running = True

    def run(self):
        """Poll the event stream and call each handler with each event item returned."""
        counter = 0
        while self._running:
            for number, handler in enumerate(self._handlers):
                handler(number, counter)
                print("reading from stream: ", self._stream_key)
                counter += 1
                sleep(2)

    def stop(self):
        """Stop polling the event stream."""
        self._running = False
        self.join()

    def start(self) -> None:
        self._running = True
        return super().start()

    def add_handler(self, callback):
        self._handlers.add(callback)

    def remove_handler(self, callback):
        self._handlers.remove(callback)


class EventHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.consumers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def subscribe(self, stream_key: str, callback):
        if stream_key in self.consumers:
            self.consumers[stream_key].add_handler(callback)
        else:
            consumer = Consumer(stream_key=stream_key, callback=callback)
            self.consumers[stream_key] = consumer
            self.consumers[stream_key].start()

    def __del__(self):
        for consumer in self.consumers.values():
            consumer.stop()


class Worker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._eventhandler = EventHandler()
        self.registered = False
        self._subscriptions = {("test-stream-key", self.handlerfunc)}

    def register(self):
        self._start_listeners()
        self.registered = True

    def _start_listeners(self):
        for subscription in self._subscriptions:
            self._eventhandler.subscribe(*subscription)

    def handlerfunc(self, number, counter):
        print(f"handler {number} doing things, counting: {counter}")


worker = Worker()


worker.register()


del worker
```

it keeps producing output like

```
reading from stream:  test-stream-key
handler 0 doing things, counting: 1
reading from stream:  test-stream-key
handler 0 doing things, counting: 2
...
```

After the `del` command I expect the garbage collection to do its magic and thereby stop the agent (incl. the `EventHandler` that has also a `__del__` method).

Interestingly, this works fine in case I do not define the `handlerfunc` as a method of `Worker` but in the global scope:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
import weakref


class Consumer(threading.Thread):
    """This class periodically reads from a stream."""

    def __init__(self, stream_key, callback):
        super().__init__()

        self._stream_key: str = stream_key
        self._handlers = {callback}

        self._running = True

    def run(self):
        """Poll the event stream and call each handler with each event item returned."""
        counter = 0
        while self._running:
            for number, handler in enumerate(self._handlers):
                handler(number, counter)
                print("reading from stream: ", self._stream_key)
                counter += 1
                sleep(2)

    def stop(self):
        """Stop polling the event stream."""
        self._running = False
        self.join()

    def start(self) -> None:
        self._running = True
        return super().start()

    def add_handler(self, callback):
        self._handlers.add(callback)

    def remove_handler(self, callback):
        self._handlers.remove(callback)


class EventHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.consumers = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def subscribe(self, stream_key: str, callback):
        if stream_key in self.consumers:
            self.consumers[stream_key].add_handler(callback)
        else:
            consumer = Consumer(stream_key=stream_key, callback=callback)
            self.consumers[stream_key] = consumer
            self.consumers[stream_key].start()

    def __del__(self):
        for consumer in self.consumers.values():
            consumer.stop()


class Worker:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._eventhandler = EventHandler()
        self.registered = False
        self._subscriptions = {("test-stream-key", handlerfunc)}

    def register(self):
        self._start_listeners()
        self.registered = True

    def _start_listeners(self):
        for subscription in self._subscriptions:
            self._eventhandler.subscribe(*subscription)


def handlerfunc(number, counter):
    print(f"handler {number} doing things, counting: {counter}")


worker = Worker()


worker.register()


del worker
```

in that case it stops after one message, more or less immediately. this is what I would expect with the class scoped method as well.

What is happening here? And is it correct to use `weakref.WeakValueDictionary()`? (obviously not) But is it at least the idea of using `weakref` correct?

Comment: "Note Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event." https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html. Example https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-stop-thread/

Comment: Thx. I get the idea. But putting in the `Event` Flag does not work for me. Anyway: from the basic idea I would expect that calling the `.stop()` of the Thread while deleting it, would have the same effect, since this sets the `self._running` flag to `False`. But by any reason this does not take effect so that the process goes on to print messages. When going through with debugging tools, it seems like the `__del__` function is not called.